# Conflicting answers when I try to find out endian-ness of my Macbook Pro

Tags: endianness

I have a Macbook Pro and am getting contradictory answers when I try to determine its endian-ness.

> Method 1

```
python -c "import sys;print sys.byteorder" tells me I am on a little endian system
```

> Method 2

I have a text file. I used `iconv` to convert it into `UTF16`. Its supposed to detect the endianness of the computer and convert it into that format. So here I go:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 file.txt > utf16.txt
file utf16.txt
utf16.txt: Big-endian UTF-16 Unicode English text
```

`vi utf16.txt` works and `hexdump -C utf16.txt` shows:

```
00000000  fe ff 00 33 00 39 00 38  00 31 00 36 00 30 00 38  |...3.9.8.1.6.0.8|

00000010  00 09 00 54 00 69 00 61  00 20 00 4a 00 75 00 61  |...T.i.a. .J.u.a|

00000020  00 6e 00 61 00 20 00 52  00 69 00 76 00 65 00 72  |.n.a. .R.i.v.e.r|

00000030  00 09 00 54 00 69 00 61  00 20 00 4a 00 75 00 61  |...T.i.a. .J.u.a|

00000040  00 6e 00 61 00 20 00 52  00 69 00 76 00 65 00 72  |.n.a. .R.i.v.e.r|

00000050  00 09 00 52 00 69 00 6f  00 20 00 54 00 69 00 61  |...R.i.o. .T.i.a|

00000060  00 6a 00 75 00 61 00 6e  00 61 00 2c 00 52 00 69  |.j.u.a.n.a.,.R.i|

00000070  00 6f 00 20 00 54 00 69  00 6a 00 75 00 61 00 6e  |.o. .T.i.j.u.a.n|

00000080  00 61 00 2c 00 52 00 ed  00 6f 00 20 00 54 00 69  |.a.,.R...o. .T.i|

00000090  00 6a 00 75 00 61 00 6e  00 61 00 2c 00 54 00 69  |.j.u.a.n.a.,.T.i|
```

if I convert it to little-endian and manually insert a BOM like this:

```
( printf "\xff\xfe" ; iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16le file.txt ) > UTF16LEBOM.txt
file UTF16LEBOM.txt
UTF16LEBOM.txt: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode English text
```

`vi UTF16LEBOM.txt` works

and `hexdump -C UTF16LEBOM.txt` shows

```
00000000  ff fe 33 00 39 00 38 00  31 00 36 00 30 00 38 00  |..3.9.8.1.6.0.8.|

00000010  09 00 54 00 69 00 61 00  20 00 4a 00 75 00 61 00  |..T.i.a. .J.u.a.|

00000020  6e 00 61 00 20 00 52 00  69 00 76 00 65 00 72 00  |n.a. .R.i.v.e.r.|

00000030  09 00 54 00 69 00 61 00  20 00 4a 00 75 00 61 00  |..T.i.a. .J.u.a.|

00000040  6e 00 61 00 20 00 52 00  69 00 76 00 65 00 72 00  |n.a. .R.i.v.e.r.|

00000050  09 00 52 00 69 00 6f 00  20 00 54 00 69 00 61 00  |..R.i.o. .T.i.a.|

00000060  6a 00 75 00 61 00 6e 00  61 00 2c 00 52 00 69 00  |j.u.a.n.a.,.R.i.|

00000070  6f 00 20 00 54 00 69 00  6a 00 75 00 61 00 6e 00  |o. .T.i.j.u.a.n.|

00000080  61 00 2c 00 52 00 ed 00  6f 00 20 00 54 00 69 00  |a.,.R...o. .T.i.|

00000090  6a 00 75 00 61 00 6e 00  61 00 2c 00 54 00 69 00  |j.u.a.n.a.,.T.i.|
```

From [this](http://betterexplained.com/articles/understanding-big-and-little-endian-byte-order/) link:

> The other approach is to include a magic number, such as 0xFEFF,
>   before every piece of data. If you read the magic number and it is
>   0xFEFF, it means the data is in the same format as your machine, and
>   all is well.
>
> **If you read the magic number and it is 0xFFFE (it is backwards), it
>   means the data was written in a format different from your own**. You'll
>   have to translate it.

Who is right and why am I getting contradictory answers?

Comment: MacBooks have Intel processors, and Intel x86 and x64 processors are little endian.

Answer (score -1):

"Endian-ness of my Macbook Pro" means nothing. You need to be more specific; different applications will have different impressions. As you've just seen, you can arbitrarily encode bytes in a file. In the end, a series of bytes is just that, and files are ultimately just a series of bytes that can be read in either fashion. In the context of programming (Stack Overflow) what's important is knowing a) Whether the input you are getting is in Big Endian or Little Endian, and b) Whether the output you send should be in Big Endian or Little Endian.

If your question is the conventional reading of files, the answer is usually Little Endian. But, for example, network data tends to be Big Endian.

Comment: if the "Endian-ness of my Macbook Pro" means nothing then why is python -c "import sys;print sys.byteorder" saying I am on a little endian system and why do we have this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness that says The Intel x86 and x86-64 series of processors use the little-endian format

Comment: The former corroborates what I said about the conventional reading of files being in Little Endian. The latter is the convention for that CPU, which is important only if you're looking at, say, assembly code. They coincidentally use the same encoding, but there are also aspects of your computer, such as the network parts of your OS, that expect Big Endian.